# Кластеризация node.js приложения

Tags: node.js, cluster

Правильно ли я понял, что при кластеризации будет создаваться несколько экземпляров одного приложения и память будет у каждого своя? То есть, если я раньше объекты состояния юзеров хранил в массиве, теперь придётся их выносить за пределы приложения? Как это реализовать?

Comment: Рекомендую для начала ознакомится с общими принципами кластеризации, её типами (горизонтальная, вертикальная) и т.д,  А вопросы задавать уже по конкретному механизму кластеризации. В противном случае на Ваш вопрос невозможно дать ответ, который уложится в допустимые границы для простого ответа.

Comment: @Темкатоже полагаю тут имеется в виду вполне конкретный модуль cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при кластеризации будет создаваться несколько экземпляров одного
>   приложения и память будет у каждого своя?

Если имеется ввиду встроенная в Node.js кластеризация, то ответ - да. На каждый **worker** [создаётся новый процесс](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works), при этом процессы взаимодействуют между собой посредством [IPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Как могут общаться между собой эти процессы? [Отправкой](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle_callback) и [приёмом](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_message) сообщений.

Пример из доки выше:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  const worker = cluster.fork();
  worker.send('hi there');

} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  process.on('message', (msg) => {
    process.send(msg);
  });
}
```

Можно это организовать и посредством одной БД, в этом случае вам ещё нужно следить за сохранностью и достоверностью данных, что является уже предметом отдельного вопроса.